# Sharepoint 2010. How to check and get current zone

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

Sharepoint central administration contains possibility to configure URL for different zones (Alternate access mappings).

Ex:

- Default Zone
- Etranet Zone

Can i with some sharepoint API determine and get current zone for user?

Comment: do you mean current zone of the site?

Comment: Yes, already found that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found how to determine current zone:

```
     SPContext.Current.Site.Zone
```